# Email attachment Drag and Drop to C drive

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, outlook

I am trying to add drag and drop functionality to my form so that I can drag an attachment from an email and it will save the attachment.

I get an error saying Required Privileges not held by client. I want to get around this.

Here is my code:

```
If e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor") Then

Dim theStream As Stream = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor"), Stream)
Dim fileGroupDescriptor As Byte() = New Byte(511) {}
theStream.Read(fileGroupDescriptor, 0, 512)

Dim fileName As New StringBuilder("")
Dim i As Integer = 76
While fileGroupDescriptor(i) <> 0
    fileName.Append(Convert.ToChar(fileGroupDescriptor(i)))
    i += 1
End While
theStream.Close()

Dim theFile As String = "c:\" + fileName.ToString() 'change the c:\ to any path you want

Dim ms As MemoryStream = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData("FileContents", True), MemoryStream)
Dim fileBytes As Byte() = New Byte(ms.Length - 1) {}
ms.Position = 0
ms.Read(fileBytes, 0, CInt(ms.Length))

Dim fs As New FileStream(theFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, CInt(fileBytes.Length))
fs.Close()
End If
```

Comment: It sound's like you don't have the permission or it's not set properly to save to that directory under Windows. See if this link help's you out: **http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/error-0x80070522-a-required-privilege-is-not-held/78cc11ec-c543-418d-9183-131318e9db8a?auth=1**. Also what line is the error coming from? If you set a breakpoint and step-through it should break on the line that's causing the probelm. My best guess is: `fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, CInt(fileBytes.Length))` or `Dim fs As New FileStream(theFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)`

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly do not have permissions to write to `c:\`.

I suggest writing to your desktop or somewhere using the `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories` object:-

```
   Dim theFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, filename.ToString)
```

Check this article out for all the options available to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.specialdirectories.aspx